# Are all web servers for a domain wildcard certificate supposed to have the same private key?

Tags: tls, key-management, rsa, csr, wildcard

If I have three web servers that all have the same CSR based on a domain, *.domain.com, does that mean all the servers have the same private key?  I know it's a short question, but I am not sure of the SO answers I have read.

[Use the same IIS RSA key on all servers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52321/use-the-same-iis-rsa-key-on-all-servers)

What I didn't understand because I am still learning is if they don't all have the same private key for that *.domain.com, doesn't that mean I need to generate a new key for each server?  I think what is getting me is I thought you could only have the same private key for the CSR based on the math, so it would have to be the same for each server in a domain wide CSR.

I do see that if I use one key on all that if one server gets compromised, they all do, but that doesn't help me because, again, I thought they all had to have the same key on a domain wildcard CSR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key is linked to the certificate, so if you use the same certificate at different places, **you also need to use the same private key**.

If you want each server to have a different key, you need to generate different certificates.

Comment: If I have one domain but ten servers, for example, then I can still have them all on the same domain just that the certificate is generated for that machine only?  So I haver server1.mydomain.com and server2.domain.com...They are all able to be on the same domain, just that I am not using a wildcard domain, so no need to have the same private key?

Comment: @johnny: it's common practice to terminate the TLS connection at the load balancer level: see [TLS termination proxy on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy). With that method, only the load balancer has access to the private key.

Comment: @johnny: `They are all able to be on the same domain, just that I am not using a wildcard domain, so no need to have the same private key?` -- no, they don't need. They may have different certificates with different key pairs.